# Вывод данных из checkbox в другой div

Tags: javascript, html

Есть список из **checkbox-ов**.
[image: Изображение к заданию]

При нажатии на любой из **чекбоксов** его данные `(текст checkbox 1/2/3/4/5)` выводятся в `div` блок. Важно, чтобы **чекбокс** выбирался по одному, а не несколько. Допустим нажали на **checkbox 1** - он вывелся, а если нажать на **checkbox 2** - **checkbox 1** пропадает и на его место встаёт **checkbox 2**.

Comment: Нужно повешать обработчик на все чекбоксы, внутри обработчика взять текущий чекбокс и добавлять его значение в див, делать текущий чекбокс checked а остальные пробежаться в цикле и если отличается от текущего, выставить checked=false, какой вопрос такой ответ был бы код подсказал бы по коду

Answer (score 2):

Описанное поведение является естественным для `input type="radio"`:

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');

onChangeValue();

function onChangeValue(){
    output.textContent = document.querySelector('input[name="rval"]:checked').value;
}
```

```html
<div id="output" style="position: fixed; top: 10px; right: 10px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold"></div>
<input type="radio" value="radio1" onchange="onChangeValue()" name="rval" checked>
<label for="radio1">Radio1</label><br>
<input type="radio" value="radio2" onchange="onChangeValue()" name="rval">
<label for="radio2">Radio2</label><br>
<input type="radio" value="radio3" onchange="onChangeValue()" name="rval">
<label for="radio3">Radio3</label><br>
<input type="radio" value="radio4" onchange="onChangeValue()" name="rval">
<label for="radio4">Radio4</label>
```

Если именно checkbox нужны, то можно сымитировать:

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');

onChangeValue(document.querySelector('[name="rval"]:checked'));

function onChangeValue(el){
    document.querySelectorAll('[name="rval"]').forEach(inp => {
        inp.checked = false;
    });
    el.checked = true;
    output.textContent = el.value;  
}
```

```html
<div id="output" style="position: fixed; top: 10px; right: 10px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold"></div>
<input type="checkbox" value="checkbox1" onchange="onChangeValue(this)" name="rval" checked>
<label for="checkbox1">Checkbox1</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="checkbox2" onchange="onChangeValue(this)" name="rval">
<label for="checkbox2">Checkbox2</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="checkbox3" onchange="onChangeValue(this)" name="rval">
<label for="checkbox3">Checkbox3</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="checkbox4" onchange="onChangeValue(this)" name="rval">
<label for="checkbox4">Checkbox4</label>
```

Если нужна возможность оставить без выбора:

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');

onChangeValue(document.querySelector('[name="rval"]:checked'));

function onChangeValue(el){
    document.querySelectorAll('[name="rval"]').forEach(inp => {
        if(el!=inp) inp.checked = false;
    });
    output.textContent = el.checked ? el.value : 'NOTHING'; 
}
```

```html
<div id="output" style="position: fixed; top: 10px; right: 10px; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold"></div>
<input type="checkbox" value="checkbox1" onchange="onChangeValue(this)" name="rval" checked>
<label for="checkbox1">Checkbox1</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="checkbox2" onchange="onChangeValue(this)" name="rval">
<label for="checkbox2">Checkbox2</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="checkbox3" onchange="onChangeValue(this)" name="rval">
<label for="checkbox3">Checkbox3</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="checkbox4" onchange="onChangeValue(this)" name="rval">
<label for="checkbox4">Checkbox4</label>
```

Comment: Вот последний вариант очень крутой. Но при вставке его на сайт в консоле всегда ошибки, вставляю ровно как у вас: 
filter.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null
    at onChangeValue (filter.js:5)
    at filter.js:2
filter.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null
    at onChangeValue (filter.js:12)
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (directory.html:265)
Пробовал даже вниз подключать скрипт отдельно, всё равно ошибку видит..

Comment: У меня один из чекбоксов имеет атрибут checked изначально. В первый вызов функции передается этот элемент. Можно заменить на `onChangeValue(document.querySelector('[name="rval"]'));` - тогда просто будет передаваться первый чекбокс и все.

Answer (score 1):

Лучшебы что-то реактивное, но вот нативный JS

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
const resultDiv = document.querySelector('.result__num');

const countChecked = () => Object.values(checkboxes).filter(el =>
  el.checked
).length;


const onchange = (e) => {
  resultDiv.innerText = countChecked()
}

checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => checkbox.addEventListener('change', onchange, false))
```

```css
.result {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.result__num {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="result">
  Результат: <span class="result__num">0<span>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="f1" />
  <label for="f1">1</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="f2" />
  <label for="f2">2</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="f3" />
  <label for="f3">3</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="f4" />
  <label for="f4">4</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Почему что-то реактивное лучше?

Comment: там пересчет прозрачнее и выборку не нужно делать руками, упрощает жизнь